# How to access the nested jsondata in angular template, i have tried this using ngFor doesn't work for me

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to access the JSON data inside my angular template but I have no idea how to do it:

JSON DATA:

```
{
    "data": {
        "active_cryptocurrencies": 2050, 
        "active_markets": 15110, 
        "bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap": 53.85, 
        "quotes": {
            "USD": {
                "total_market_cap": 207937227143.0, 
                "total_volume_24h": 10373130891.0
            }
        }, 
        "last_updated": 1540293278
    }, 
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1540292653, 
        "error": null
    }
}
```

mycomponent.ts

```
jsonData: any[];

private _url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/'; 

constructor(private http: Http) {
    http.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/")
        .subscribe(response =>{
            this.jsonData = response.json().data.quotes;
            console.log(this.jsonData);
         });
}
```

So I am trying to show these details in the angular template but it says `cannot 
 find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-object-ngfor`

Can you please help me as to how to go with this as json here is little messy?
I simply want to show the JSON data in my html template.

Comment: Your code is working. Show your views code - this should be the error producing part.

Comment: Use **HttpClient** not the old and deprecated http, then the quotes is in response.data.quotes

Comment: @Eliseo i am able to fetch data and print it into console , i am asking how to show the data in angular html template

Answer (score 3):

Edited:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit,Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from  '@angular/http' ;

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  Hello, Angular
    <ul *ngFor="let item of data">      
      <li>active_markets :{{item.active_markets}}</li>
      <li>bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap:{{item.bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap}}</li>
      <li>last_updated: {{item.last_updated}} </li>
      <li>
          <ul *ngFor="let q of item.quotes">        
             <li>total_market_cap: {{q.total_market_cap}}</li>
            <li>total_volume_24h: {{q.total_volume_24h}}</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  data:any=[];
  private _url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  async ngOnInit(){    
    let obj =(await this.http.get(this._url).toPromise()).json();
```

you should convert  your json object

```
   this.data= Object.keys(obj).map(function(e){
    Object.keys(obj[e]).forEach(function(k){
          if(typeof obj[e][k] == "object" && (obj[e][k]!=undefined || obj[e][k]!=null )) {
            obj[e][k] = Object.keys(obj[e][k]).map(function(l){
             return obj[e][k][l];
            });
          }
        }return obj[e];
        });
    );}}
```

Comment: i am able to fetch data succesfully , i just want to show this via HTML template in angular using ngFor or any other loop so that i don't have to  render it one by one :)